# Juju bootstrap to openstack failing with 404 message

Tags: juju, openstack

I'm trying to get juju-core to bootstrap to my OpenStack cloud.  I pulled the environment file from Openstack but when I try the boot strap I see a "404" error returned from Openstack.  It appears that the http message is not built correctly but it's likely a configuration issue.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

```
# To use Juju with your Openstack cloud:
```

## 1. Run: apt-get install juju

## 2. Copy this file to $HOME/.juju/environments.yaml

## 3. Complete any empty fields

## 4. Run 'juju bootstrap' and deploy services!

#

```
environments:
  openstack:
    type: openstack
    auth-url: http://controller:5000/v3
    auth-mode: userpass
    use-floating-ip: true
    # Please provide the UUID of the network to use if you have
    # more than one network configured for your tenant.
    # network:
    region: RegionOne
    username: admin
    # Please provide the password you use to access the
    # OpenStack cloud.
    password:
    tenant-name: admin


juju bootstrap -v
Bootstrap failed, cleaning up the environment.
ERROR there was an issue examining the environment: authentication failed.

Please ensure the credentials are correct. A common mistake is
to specify the wrong tenant. Use the OpenStack "project" name
for tenant-name in your environment configuration.
```

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Anybody???@eric